# jquery modal show automatically after timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap modal to show a log in or sign up modal and I want the modal to pop up after a certain amount of time, and I would like the modal to only close after they sign up or log in, basically it needs to restrict access to the site after it pop up, so they are forced to sign up or they cant continue viewing the site, i'm using bootstrap.js, I can trigger the modal from a link but I want it to automatically show up after like 30 seconds, please help, not to good with jquery, thanks.

My modal

```
<!-- Start modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <h4 id="myModalLabel">Login member</h4>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal marginbot-clear">  
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="control-group margintop30">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Username</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Login now</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- End modal -->
```

Modal jquery from bootstrap file below

```
!function ($) {

  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;


     /* MODAL CLASS DEFINITION
  * ====================== */

  var Modal = function (element, options) {
this.options = options
this.$element = $(element)
  .delegate('[data-dismiss="modal"]', 'click.dismiss.modal', $.proxy(this.hide, this))
this.options.remote && this.$element.find('.modal-body').load(this.options.remote)
 }

  Modal.prototype = {

  constructor: Modal

, toggle: function () {
    return this[!this.isShown ? 'show' : 'hide']()
  }

, show: function () {
    var that = this
      , e = $.Event('show')

    this.$element.trigger(e)

    if (this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.isShown = true

    this.escape()

    this.backdrop(function () {
      var transition = $.support.transition && that.$element.hasClass('fade')

      if (!that.$element.parent().length) {
        that.$element.appendTo(document.body) //don't move modals dom position
      }

      that.$element.show()

      if (transition) {
        that.$element[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
      }

      that.$element
        .addClass('in')
        .attr('aria-hidden', false)

       that.enforceFocus()

         transition ?
            that.$element.one($.support.transition.end, function () {     that.$element.focus().trigger('shown') }) :
        that.$element.focus().trigger('shown')

    })
  }

, hide: function (e) {
    e && e.preventDefault()

    var that = this

    e = $.Event('hide')

    this.$element.trigger(e)

    if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.isShown = false

    this.escape()

    $(document).off('focusin.modal')

    this.$element
      .removeClass('in')
      .attr('aria-hidden', true)

    $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
      this.hideWithTransition() :
      this.hideModal()
  }

, enforceFocus: function () {
    var that = this
    $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
      if (that.$element[0] !== e.target && !that.$element.has(e.target).length) {
        that.$element.focus()
      }
    })
  }

, escape: function () {
    var that = this
    if (this.isShown && this.options.keyboard) {
      this.$element.on('keyup.dismiss.modal', function ( e ) {
        e.which == 27 && that.hide()
      })
    } else if (!this.isShown) {
      this.$element.off('keyup.dismiss.modal')
    }
  }

, hideWithTransition: function () {
    var that = this
      , timeout = setTimeout(function () {
          that.$element.off($.support.transition.end)
          that.hideModal()
        }, 500)

    this.$element.one($.support.transition.end, function () {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
      that.hideModal()
    })
  }

, hideModal: function () {
    var that = this
    this.$element.hide()
    this.backdrop(function () {
      that.removeBackdrop()
      that.$element.trigger('hidden')
    })
  }

, removeBackdrop: function () {
    this.$backdrop && this.$backdrop.remove()
    this.$backdrop = null
  }

, backdrop: function (callback) {
    var that = this
      , animate = this.$element.hasClass('fade') ? 'fade' : ''

    if (this.isShown && this.options.backdrop) {
      var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate

      this.$backdrop = $('<div class="modal-backdrop ' + animate + '" />')
        .appendTo(document.body)

      this.$backdrop.click(
        this.options.backdrop == 'static' ?
          $.proxy(this.$element[0].focus, this.$element[0])
        : $.proxy(this.hide, this)
      )

      if (doAnimate) this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth // force reflow

      this.$backdrop.addClass('in')

      if (!callback) return

      doAnimate ?
        this.$backdrop.one($.support.transition.end, callback) :
        callback()

    } else if (!this.isShown && this.$backdrop) {
      this.$backdrop.removeClass('in')

      $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade')?
        this.$backdrop.one($.support.transition.end, callback) :
        callback()

    } else if (callback) {
      callback()
    }
  }
 }


 /* MODAL PLUGIN DEFINITION
 * ======================= */

var old = $.fn.modal

 $.fn.modal = function (option) {
  return this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this)
    , data = $this.data('modal')
    , options = $.extend({}, $.fn.modal.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object'     && option)
     if (!data) $this.data('modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
    if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
  })
    }

 $.fn.modal.defaults = {
  backdrop: true
, keyboard: true
, show: true
 }

  $.fn.modal.Constructor = Modal


 /* MODAL NO CONFLICT
  * ================= */

  $.fn.modal.noConflict = function () {
$.fn.modal = old
return this
 }


 /* MODAL DATA-API
 * ============== */

 $(document).on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
var $this = $(this)
  , href = $this.attr('href')
  , $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')))    //strip for ie7
  , option = $target.data('modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({ remote:!/#/.test(href) && href     }, $target.data(), $this.data())

e.preventDefault()

$target
  .modal(option)
  .one('hide', function () {
    $this.focus()
  })
 })

}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Be aware that a modal is not necessarily going to prevent someone from viewing your content.  Anyone who knows how to use a DOM inspector can simply hide the modal.  If you really want to lock it down, rely on your backend code to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#myModal').fadeIn(200);
    }, 30000); // milliseconds
});
```

Beyond that, we'll need to see some code to get a better idea of your setup.

You really don't *need* jQuery for this, though  (although jQuery makes it easy to fade in/out). Pure JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

  setTimeout(function() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
  }, 30000);
}
```

**Update**

Also, you can use bootstrap's built-in modal functions for showing/hiding. Simply make a new file such as **custom.js** to hold a script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }, 30000); // milliseconds
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i'm just using the bootstrap.js file that comes with bootstrap

Comment: @user2680299 I've updated my answer. Using `.modal('show')` should work better

Comment: i added the bootstrap modal code, its not working for me, is it because i have a link that uses the modal too ?

Comment: You don't need to edit the modal code. Use the functions provided by this code such as `.modal('show')` or `.modal(hide)` and put it in your own custom js file

Comment: I did what you said and its not working, site deals.betteroffers.com, thanks